# Difference between passing functions with arguments to a decorator in different scenario

Tags: python, methods, python-decorators, args, keyword-argument

I got this code from Corey Schafer's tutorial of Python decorators. I am giving below two codes.

- CODE- 1

```
def decorator_function(original_function):
    def wrapper_function():
        print("Wrapper executed before {}".format(original_function.__name__))
        return original_function()
    return wrapper_function

@decorator_function
def display():
    print("display func ran")

def function_info(name,age):
    print("Function info has {} and {} as arguments.".format(name, age))

display()
function_info('John',23)
```

This executes the code properly. But if we take the function_info(name,age) method, it's passing arguments, instead it's not giving any error.

While, below stated code takes args and kwargs as arguments.

- CODE - 2

```
def decorator_function(original_function):
    def wrapper_function(*args,**kwargs):
        print("Wrapper executed before {}".format(original_function.__name__))
        return original_function(*args,**kwargs)
    return wrapper_function

@decorator_function
def display():
    print("display func ran")

def function_info(name,age):
    print("Function info has {} and {} as arguments.".format(name, age))

display() 
function_info('Jim',23)
```

Can anyone explain me the difference?

Why in CODE - 1, when both methods are in the same decorator, doesn't gives any error for function_info(name,age) but, in CODE - 2 when both methods are decorated separately, function_info(name, age) requires args and kwargs?

Comment: There's something wrong with the post formatting. (Mixed back-ticks (`) with single-quotes (') ?)

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your question. Could you maybe show some code that is raising an error that you weren't expecting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output is basically the same for both functions- no matter if you are using the arguments `*args,**kwargs` (tested with https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_python_interpreter).

CODE-1:

> Wrapper executed before display
> display func ran
> Function info has John and 23 as arguments.

CODE - 2:

> Wrapper executed before display
> display func ran
> Function info has Jim and 23 as arguments.

The thing is that the decorator is only used on the function display which has no arguments.

If you put

```
@decorator_function
def function_info(name,age):
    print("Function info has {} and {} as arguments.".format(name, age))
```

then - for both codes - you need need `*args,**kwargs` because the wrapper_function() is executed before function_info() is executed. And as function_info() takes arguments, you also require arguments for the wrapper_function() in the decorator, otherwise the interpreter complains that there are two arguments for a function which takes none.

Output:

> Wrapper executed before display
> display func ran
> Wrapper executed before function_info
> Function info has Jim and 23 as arguments.

Comment: Thanks, now I got it.